# How to do class free inheritance in JavaScript (Crockford style)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

### Background

I am trying to improve my JS skills, and with that I am watching some of the big entities in the JS world. Such an entity is Douglas Crockford, and he is preaching a class free paradigm.

After watching him at Nordic js (I highly recommend) I was baffled by the way he [makes objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0&t=23m15s) without any taxonomy whatsoever.

### Problem

I am now trying to replicate his slides into a simple example, that uses Exceptions, but I can't get it to work right.

I don't understand how my `UniformityException.js` file can reuse the code from `Exception.js` and be consistent with Crockford's ideology.

The problem here is that my `specs` variable in `UniformityException.js` only has a `write` method, and rightfully so.

After watching the slides many times, I can't understand how to change this code without making heavy use of `Object.assign`.

### Code

**Exception.js**

```
"use strict";

let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let _ = require("underscore");

let Exception = function(args){

    let DEFAULT_PROPS = {
        exceptionName: "Exception",
        outputFolder: "./ErrorLogs/",
        fileExtension: ".txt"
    };

    DEFAULT_PROPS.message = "A generic exception occurred.";
    DEFAULT_PROPS.outputFile = DEFAULT_PROPS.exceptionName  + "_" + _.now();

    let props = Object.assign(DEFAULT_PROPS, args);

    let write = function(){
        jsonfile.writeFile(props.outputFolder + props.outputFile + props.fileExtension, props.message, error => {
            if(_.isNull(error) || _.isUndefined(error))
                console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return Object.freeze({
        write
    });
};

module.exports = Exception;
```

**UniformityException.js**

```
"use strict";

let Exception = require("./Exception.js");
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let _ = require("underscore");

let UniformityException = function(args){

    let specs = Exception({
        exceptionName: "UniformityException",
        fileExtension: ".json"
    });

    let write = function(info){
        jsonfile.writeFile(specs.outputFolder + specs.outputFile, info, error => {
            if(_.isNull(error) || _.isUndefined(error))
                console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return Object.freeze({
        write
    });
};

module.exports = UniformityException;
```

**index.js**

```
"use strict";

let UniformityException = require("./Exceptions/UniformityException.js");

let myUniformException = UniformityException();

myUniformException.write({fruit: "banana"});
```

### Questions

1. How do I make `UniformityException.js` reuse the code from `Exception.js` in a way that fits the Crockford style?

As usual, keywords like `new`, `this` and `Object.create` are to be avoided.

Comment: What part do you want to reuse? The `write` function?

Comment: Everything. But in this case, I want to reuse the `props`  variable from the `Exception.js`

Comment: With the above code you can't, because the only property that `Expection` exposes is `write`. `props` is a privately held variable inside its constructor. If you want that part publicly available you have to add it to the return (frozen) object.

Comment: I know that. Problem is that I don't know if this is in accordance with Crockford's slides :S

Comment: Wait, Crockford now opposes even `Object.create`?

Comment: "*without any taxonomy whatsoever*" - that's not true. He just doesn't use prototypical inheritance for some reason. His functions (dare I call them classes?) *do* have a hierarchy. And in your case, `UniformityException` just cannot extend `Exception`, because its `write` method is not reusable.

Comment: @Bergi, yes he no longer uses `Object.create`. Also, these are not classes (this is supposed to be "class free") and I don't have a hierarchy per se. For further information, you are welcome to see the full event (i link  to it) or to read the comments previously posted here.

Comment: I dont see why exposing `props` should be against the "indespensable" law of the great Crockford. It's basically what `{other} = other_constructor(spec)` is doing in his slides. *On a side note:* There are lot of people who disobey the "godfather father of JS" and are still great developers! Being too dogmatic will not make you a better developer in any language :)

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix There always is a hierarchy of reuse and common property names. It's duck typing in all its glory. Yeah, we shouldn't call them "classes", but they still have a type hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you need

In order to do that, you need to use the [Destructuring assignment pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). With this pattern, the following code from the slides:

```
function animal(spec) {
  let {body, type, name} = spec;
}
```

Will get converted to the following:

```
function animal(spec) {
    let body = spec.body;
    let type = spec.type;
    let name = spec.name;
}
```

This is in reality the ECMA6 version of the factory pattern, as described in this blog post [constructors VS factories](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029152324/http://ericleads.com/2013/01/javascript-constructor-functions-vs-factory-functions).

With this in mind, we can now move to the code.

### Code

**index.js**

```
"use strict";

let _ = require("underscore");
let Exception = require("./Exceptions/Exception.js");
let UniformityException = require("./Exceptions/UniformityException.js");

let jsonParams = {
    outputFolder: "./ErrorLogs/",
    fileExtension: ".txt",
    message: {info: "A generic error ocurred."},
    exceptionName: "Exception",
};

let myException = Exception(jsonParams);
myException.write();

jsonParams.fileExtension  = ".json";
jsonParams.exceptionName = "UniformException";
jsonParams.outputFileName = jsonParams.exceptionName + "_" + _.now();

let myUniformException = UniformityException(jsonParams);
myUniformException.write({
    fruit: "banana"
});
```

**Exception.js**

```
"use strict";

let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let _ = require("underscore");

let Exception = function(args) {
    let {
        outputFolder,
        fileExtension,
        exceptionName,
        message,
        outputFileName,
    } = args;

    outputFileName = outputFileName|| (exceptionName  + "_" + _.now());

    let filePath = outputFolder + outputFileName + fileExtension;

    let write = function() {
        jsonfile.writeFile(filePath, message, error => {
            if (!_.isNull(error) && !_.isUndefined(error))
                console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return Object.freeze({
        filePath,
        write
    });
};

module.exports = Exception;
```

**UniformityException.js**

```
"use strict";

let Exception = require("./Exception.js");
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
let _ = require("underscore");

let UniformityException = function(args) {

    let {filePath} = Exception(args),

        write = function(info) {
            jsonfile.writeFile(filePath, info, error => {
                if (!_.isNull(error) && !_.isUndefined(error))
                    console.log(error);
            });
        };

    return Object.freeze({
        filePath,
        write
    });
};

module.exports = UniformityException;
```

A thing I would like to point out, is that your **factory functions should all start with a lowercase letter** (`function animal`), and could follow the camelCase convention and name it '`animalConstructor()`'.

Typically, by convention, constructor functions which require the use of `new` are name with an first Uppercase letter (`function Animal`). To avoid confusion in the future you should rename your exceptions.

### Additional

Another resource I also highly recommend is from The Empire of Evil:

- https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/crockford%E2%80%99s-2014-object-creation-pattern

Which is in my opinion an accurate interpretation of Crockford's factory functions.

Hope it helped !

Comment: I re-did my answer, I hope you like it, Flame @Flame_Phoenix

Comment: *"In order to do that, you need to use the Destructuring assignment pattern."* What is the *that* you are talking about? Destructuring assignment doesn't enable *anything* that wasn't possible before. This is misleading. The whole answer seems to focus on *how* to do something instead of *what* to do. As far as I can tell, the important part was to export `filePath` on the `Exception` object (which is basically what I wrote, i.e. only what is exposed can be reused).

Comment: Soldeplata's answer is far better than yours, as it clearly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can only "reuse" what is retuned by `Exception`. I.e. if you want to be able to access `props` directly you need to expose it. There is no way around it.

This is actually in line with the visibility model you find in other class based languangues: private members (e.g. `props`) can only be accessed by the class itself. If a child class should have access, many languages offer a "protected" mode, but JS doesn't have something like that.

---

Instead of adding it to the object returned by the function, you could consider making `Exception` accept a function that it passes its "private" members to, just like `Promise` does. Not sure what Crockford says about that though.